# Cost per user goes down, when more users

Tags: algorithms

I am working on a pricing formula, currently the cost per user looks similar to this.
However, I want to put this in a formula so that I can just input users and it will output the cost.
As you can see the cost/user goes down the more users you have. It doesnt have to be exact to this table, but close to it.

I have been playing around in Excel and desmos for hours but I really just lack the math knowledge to do this. Hope someone can help me with creating a formula that looks like the table.

The first 100 users are free, and after 100,000 the price/user stays the same.

[image]

Comment: My suggestion: Set
$$
\text{Price}\approx 46\cdot \sqrt{\text{number of users}}
$$
What's your opinion on this? Does it work reasonably well? Of course you would add the limits $100 \ldots 100~000$

Comment: It is close to it, but on some numbers there is to much difference it seems like.

Comment: Making an approximation is always a compromise between accuracy and simplicity of the expression. Perhaps one could add more terms to the expression ...

Comment: Totally agree, what terms could I add to the expression? It looks like to the range of 3000 til 20000, there is a 600 euro difference. Is there something we can add to close the gap between those numbers?

Comment: I think between $5~000$ and $10~000$ there should be a "break point", because something weird happens at that area. The price doesn't increase almost at all. I made a log-log plot of the values, and for my second suggestion I have
$$
\text{Price}\approx
\begin{cases}
33.6\cdot N^{0.558},~100<N<7~500 \\
10.77\cdot N^{0.639},~7~500 \leq N < 100~000 
\end{cases}
$$
where $N$ is the number of users. It's not a continous function, but perhaps it's a starting point ...

Comment: Also: if you don't strictly need a mathematical expression, but rather you can make a small script that returns some values, you could use something like Python and Numpy. In Nympy, there's a command "numpy.interp" for interpolation ...

Comment: Great! That works really well. The results up to 20k are pretty accurate. I will test around a bit with it.